# Get total Call Duration in Android

Tags: android, call, logging, duration

How can get the call duration from phone memory ? I get the calls duration from Android.provider.CallLogs.calls but if removed the CallLogs i am not able to fetch call log.

Answer (score 1):

Use PhoneStateListener, store the start time when the phone goes off hook and the stop time when the phone goes on hook. Then calculate the duration.